# Multi-dimensional indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I checked the [Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) and s.o. on this but I couldn't find an answer. Maybe it can't be done.

Basically I have an array `probabilities` of shape (3,4,5). In the 3rd dimension there are 5 elements, which together sum to 1. The element index in the third dimension that I want corresponds to the values in the array `index` of shape (3,4). Makes sense?

So if `probabilities[0,0,:]` is equal to `[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]` and `index[0,0]` is equal to `2`, then I want the 3rd element which is `0.2`.

I tried `probabilities[index]` and other things, but no luck.

Can this be done without a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a sample array:

```
In [291]: A = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
In [292]: A[0,0,:]
Out[292]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
In [293]: A[0,0,2]
Out[293]: 2
```

Make a sample idx:

```
In [294]: idx = np.random.randint(0,4,(2,3),int)
In [295]: idx
Out[295]: 
array([[0, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

These are index values for the 3rd dimension.  Make arrays for indexing on the 1st 2 dimensions:

```
In [299]: I,J=np.ix_(np.arange(A.shape[0]),np.arange(A.shape[1]))
In [300]: I,J
Out[300]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]), array([[0, 1, 2]]))
In [301]: A[I,J,idx]
Out[301]: 
array([[ 0,  7,  8],
       [13, 16, 21]])
```

test:

```
In [302]: A[0,1,3]
Out[302]: 7
In [304]: A[1,2,1]
Out[304]: 21
```

There are various ways of getting those `I,J`.  `np.ix_` is an easy one.  So is `np.ogrid`, `np.mgrid` or even `np.meshgrid`.

```
In [306]: I,J = np.mgrid[0:2,0:3]
In [307]: I,J
Out[307]: 
(array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]))
In [308]: A[I,J,idx]
Out[308]: 
array([[ 0,  7,  8],
       [13, 16, 21]])
```